# Does Zz'Rot Portal make use of Garens W passive?

Tags: league-of-legends

[Zz'Rot Portal](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Zz%27Rot_Portal)

> Spawns a Void Gate at target location for 150 seconds. Every 4 seconds the gate creates a volatile Voidspawn that travels down the nearest lane, attacking enemy minions and exploding when attacking structures, but ignoring champions and void targets. 150 second cooldown.
>
> **Every additional Voidspawn after the third one gains damage equal to 50% of your armor + 50% of your magic resistance.**

Garen gains 20% additional Armor through his W passive.

**Is this bonus armor taken into calculation for the Voidspawns?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes it is!**

It wouldn't be like that if the voidspawn would scale of **base** armor and magic resitance

Comment: Does it only last the duration of his W or does it calculate once as it spawns. EDIT: Haven't played Garen in a long time, forgot his W has a passive as well as active.

Comment: The active component doesn't give any stats. I don't understand your comment